# Javascript function works only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get prescription details of particular patient and the corresponding result is displayed in modal window. Problem is first result is obtained only on 2nd click. On successive click result of previous data is obtained. Below is my HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold">
            <td></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Registered On</td>
            <td>View Prescription</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="id" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="age" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="reg_on" type="text"></td>
        <td>
            <button id="view_prescription_from_patient_list" value="register" onclick="view_prescription_from_patient_list(this.value)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <div class="modal_show"></div>
```

```js
function view_prescription_from_patient_list(patient_id) {
    var dataString = "get_what=prescription_list_for_patient_list&patient_id=" + patient_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_get_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
            $('.modal_show').append(response);
        }
    })
}
```

I tried `on.click` method within javascript but that also has the same problem.

Comment: try to watch the variable `patient_id` in the function. From my point of view, the value will be "register".

Comment: Yes the value returned will be `register`. do you want to send some number to that function ?

Comment: value="register" has some number attached to it

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a value of "register" (`this.value` from the button clicked).

Instead use jQuery to connect and handler the click event (delete the inline `onclick` handler).

e.g.

```
$('#view_prescription_from_patient_list').click(function(){ 
        var patient_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name=id]').val();
        var dataString = "get_what=prescription_list_for_patient_list&patient_id=" +  patient_id;
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_get_data.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response) {
                $('.modal_show').append(response);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

This will fetch the patent-id from the `name="id"` `TD` (which presumably has the ID value - but not shown in your example HTML).

If your code does not follow the DOM elements it references you will also need to wrap it in a DOM ready handler:

```
$(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Note: `$(function(){` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Code with jquery `on.('click'` and you can get patient_id from the parent td
Like `$(this).parent().parent().find('input[name=id]').val();`

This code may help you to understand

```js
$('#view_prescription_from_patient_list').on('click',function(){

    var patientId = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name=id]').val();
    var dataString = "get_what=prescription_list_for_patient_list&patient_id="+patientId;

    $.ajax(
            {
                type:"GET",
                url:"ajax_get_data.php",
                data:dataString,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(response)
                {
                    $('.modal_show').append(response);
                }
            }
    )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold">
            <td></td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Registered On</td>
            <td>View Prescription</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr  class="text-center">
            <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="id" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="age" type="text"></td>
            <td><input name="reg_on" type="text"></td>
            <td><button id="view_prescription_from_patient_list" value="register" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You are still fetching the id of the button, not the patient ID.

Comment: Better: Looks like a cut & paste from `Matthew` 's answer :) Note: `closest()` is more reliable than `parent().parent()` (and usually shorter)

Answer (score 0):

You're reading wrong value as pointed out in previous answers. 
I'd suggest also to use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

    $('#view_prescription_from_patient_list').on('click', function(){
        var patient_id = $('[name="id"]', $(this).closest('tr')).val(),
            dataString = "get_what=prescription_list_for_patient_list&patient_id="+patient_id;
        $.ajax({
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

---

If you really need to stick to `onclick` attribute for some reason (althought you shouldn't), pass the button to the method:

```
<button id="view_prescription_from_patient_list" value="register" onclick="view_prescription_from_patient_list(this)">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
</button>
```

and then in JS:

```
function view_prescription_from_patient_list(btn) {
    var patient_id = $('[name="id"]', $(btn).closest('tr')).val(),
        dataString = "get_what=prescription_list_for_patient_list&patient_id=" + patient_id;
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery you can wire the "onclick" event of your button using jQuery.

You need to wire your event handler up like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#view_prescription_from_patient_list').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var patientId = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name=id]').val();

        // do your ajax call here...
    });
});
```